# [samsung] tag is overly influenced by marketing department

Tags: support, tags

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/65561

I think the [samsung](/questions/tagged/samsung) tag is way too marketing-driven. A user suggested replacing this:

> Based in South Korea, the Samsung
>   group is one of the biggest
>   multinational conglomerate
>   corporation. The Korean technology
>   advancement can well be seen in their
>   products - specifically the cellphone
>   segment. Samsung Telecommunications
>   which manufactures mobile phones of a
>   low-end as well as high end
>   sophisticated smartphones is one
>   mobile industry game changer.

with this:

> From the coolest conventional and
>   brightest smart phones, to the most
>   stylish touchscreens, bars, sliders
>   and feature-rich devices with full
>   QWERTY keyboards, Samsung makes you
>   more mobile, your way.

Both descriptions are horrible.

I imagine most people know that Samsung makes everything from giant industrial ships to semiconductors to cellular telephones; apparently they also run a successful theme park and insurance business. Neat.

But what does the [samsung] tag mean *here*? Anything? Of the nine questions currently using it, several are for [android](/questions/tagged/android), several are for [symbian](/questions/tagged/symbian), and several are for [j2me](/questions/tagged/j2me).

Is there a policy I've missed about tag wiki descriptions being written by a marketing department?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Dumb tag. Burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: Awesome dragon. I almost feel sorry for the tag.

Comment: @sarnold *almost*

Comment: While I agree with the burnination, I do wonder whether the same policy ought to be applied to other “company name” tags. Some have well-written tag wikis, etc., but still add no real value.

Answer (score 6):

Interesting. I took a look through some company tags. When the company only makes one thing, it looks ok:

> Oracle is a relational DBMS (Database
>   Management System) created by Oracle
>   Corporation. It supports a large
>   number of languages and application
>   development frameworks. Its primary
>   languages are SQL, PL/SQL and Java.

Some big companies have a description of the tag:

> Apple is the company that manufactures
>   Macs and iOS devices. This tag is too
>   general to be useful on most
>   questions; consider using tags more
>   relevant to the OS and device/computer
>   you're targeting.

Some have nothing:

> The ibm tag has no wiki summary, would
>   you like to help us create it?

And some have weird corp-stuff:

> Microsoft Corporation is an American
>   public multinational corporation
>   headquartered in Redmond, Washington,
>   USA that develops, manufactures,
>   licenses, and supports a wide range of
>   products and services predominantly
>   related to computing through its
>   various product divisions.

or

> Google Inc. is an American
>   multinational public corporation
>   invested in Internet search, cloud
>   computing, and advertising
>   technologies

I think I'd like to see Microsoft and Google get the Apple treatment, heh heh. There is no way reading those descriptions will help someone who is considering putting that tag on a question.

Comment: Given the description on the [tag:apple] tag it would make more sense to kill it (and perhaps even the [tag:microsoft] and [tag:google] tags too)

Comment: @ChrisF as long as you can prevent people from using it - I certainly don't find either of them useful from a "let's follow this tag" POV. They seem to be excellent newbie-detectors though.